# UNPIVOT statement works in 2012 but not in 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

The following query works fine in SQL Server 2012 and 2014 but fails in 2005:

```
SELECT 
    MANDT,
    SCHGRUP,
    SPROG,
    SCHNR,
    WkDay,
    SHIFTID 
FROM TC38A
UNPIVOT (ShiftID FOR WkDay IN (TPROG1,TPROG2,TPROG3,TPROG4,TPROG5,TPROG6,TPROG7)) AS U
WHERE SCHGRUP = 'L1'
```

The error message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
```

I've stared at it and looked at documentation, but I can't seem to figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the DB compatibility level:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> When PIVOT and UNPIVOT are used against databases that are upgraded to SQL Server 2005 or later, the compatibility level of the database must be set to 90 or higher. For information about how to set the database compatibility level, see sp_dbcmptlevel (Transact-SQL).